# Область видимости Javascript. Как заставить код работать?

Tags: javascript

К документу подключено 2 js скрипта: jquery и main.js.

Код на самой странице с приложением:

```
$(function() {
    var manager = new ApplicationManager();
    manager.init();
});
```

main.js:

```
/**
 * Created with JetBrains PhpStorm.
 */

ApplicationModule = function ()
{
    this.title = "";
    this.content = "";

    this.render = function()
    {
        var elem = $("#content");
        var title = $("title");
        elem.html(this.getContent());
        title.text(this.getTitle());
    }

    this.init = function()
    {
        alert("Module inited!");
    }

    this.init();
}

ApplicationWidget = function(name)
{

    this.content = "";

    this.render = function()
    {
        var identity = "#" + this.getName();
        var content = $(identity);
        content.html(this.getContent());
    }

    this.init = function()
    {
        this.name = name;
        alert("Widget '"+this.getName()+"' inited!");
    }

    this.init();
}

ApplicationPage = function(url) {

    this.url = url;
    this.module = null;
    this.widgets = [];

    this.render = function()
    {
        this.getModule().render();

        var wgs = this.getWidgets();
        for (var i in wgs)
            wgs[i].render();

    }

    this.init = function()
    {
        alert("Page '"+this.getUrl()+"' inited!");
    }

    this.init();
}

ApplicationManager = function()
{
    this.applicationPages = [];
    this.currentPage = null;

    this.addApplicationPage = function(applicationPage)
    {
        try{
            this.applicationPages[applicationPage.url] = applicationPage;
            alert("123");
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

    this.getApplicationPage = function(url)
    {
        try{

            if (typeof (this.applicationPages[url]) == 'undefined')
                throw "Page not loaded";

            var page = this.applicationPages[url];
            if (!page instanceof ApplicationPage)
                throw "Page with URL: "+ url +" not loaded.";
            return page;

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

    this.initPage = function()
    {
        $("a").live('click', function() {
            history.pushState( null, null, this.href );
            var urlReq = this.href;
            $.post(
                urlReq,
                {},
                function(data){

                    var appPage = new ApplicationPage(urlReq);

                    var module = new ApplicationModule();
                    module.setTitle(data.module.title);
                    module.setContent(data.module.content);
                    appPage.registerModule(module);

                    var widgets = [];
                    for(var wg in data.widgets){
                        var toWg = new ApplicationWidget(data.widgets[wg].name);
                        toWg.setContent(data.widgets[wg].content);
                        appPage.registerWidget(toWg);
                    }

                    appPage.render();

                    manager.addApplicationPage(appPage); // !!!Не видит!!!

                },
                'json'
            );
            return false;
        });

        $( window ).bind( "popstate", function( e ) {
            var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;
            var urlReq = returnLocation.href;
            $.post(
                urlReq,
                {},
                function(data){
                },
                'json'
            );
        });
    }

    this.init = function()
    {
        this.initPage();
    }

}
```

Так вот в методе ApplicationManager.initPage() я обращаюсь к той самой переменной manager объявленной на главной странице. Ничерта не работает. Пробывал сделать иначе:

Объявлял не "ApplicationManager = fun...", а "var ApplicationManager = ..." и в методе initPage() обращался к нему как к ApplicationManager.addApplicationPage(). Все равно не видит.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб экземпляр ApplicationManager был виден везде и всюду?

п.с. Не обращайте внимания на использование геттеров-сеттеров. Я сюда их просто не стал выкладывать, потому как буковок и так много.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо просто убрать `var` при обьявлении:

```
 $(function() {
    manager = new ApplicationManager();
    manager.init();
});
```

`var manager = ...` внутри функции обьявляет локальную переменную `manager` а без `var` код пытается прочитать глобальную `manager` если не удалось то создаёт новую глобальную 
переменную `manager`

**PS** можно так:

```
 var manager;
 $(function() {
    manager = new ApplicationManager();
    manager.init();
});
```

***UPD:***:

```
AM = f(){
    var method = f(data){};
    this.method = method;
    this.init = f(){
        $.post(/*..*/, f(data){method(data);});
    }
}
```